# Python bpy 2.8 render directly to matrix/array

Tags: python, rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I'm new to working with both Blender and bpy, and I'm trying to render directly into Python. Best case, I could render directly from bpy 2.82 into a byte stream or numpy matrix.

I've been trying to follow the instructions here https://ammous88.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/blender-access-render-results-pixels-directly-from-python-2/, using `bpy.data.images["Viewer Node"].pixels`, but it's returning something of size 262,144 which doesn't make any sense. The link was written for Blender version 2.7, so I assume the API changed somehow between the two.

I have `bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x` and `bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y` set to 320 and 480 respectively, so I would assume there would be 320x480x4=614,400 total pixels.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do in Blender version 2.82?

Here's the code from the link above:

````
import bpy
import numpy as np
 
# switch on nodes
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links
  
# clear default nodes
for n in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(n)
  
# create input render layer node
rl = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')      
rl.location = 185,285
 
# create output node
v = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeViewer')   
v.location = 750,210
v.use_alpha = False
 
# Links
links.new(rl.outputs[0], v.inputs[0])  # link Image output to Viewer input
 
# render
bpy.ops.render.render()
 
# get viewer pixels
pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels
print(len(pixels)) # size is always width * height * 4 (rgba)
 
# copy buffer to numpy array for faster manipulation
arr = np.array(pixels[:])
```
````

Comment: You may need to check your render resolution setting to be at 100%.

Comment: check out answers to this question, especially https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3054/111042

Comment: 262,144 = 256*256*4. 256 is the default size of the viewer node image

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195289/compositor-viewer-node-output-never-updates-when-rendering-via-python-script?rq=1

Comment: render_res = bpy.data.images["Render Result"].pixels returns None actually